# Redux updating state for all items within an array

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to tell react/redux to upvote a likeCount when ADD_LIKE is called from the reducer.

However its upvoting the number for **all post items**

How can i do something like.

`if(action.id === post.id)` then do   `likes: state.likes + 1`

That way it can only upvote for that one post only.

```
case ADD_LIKE:
    // console.log(action.id)
    return({
        ...state,
        likes: state.likes + 1
    })
```

**Actions.js**

```
export const postLike = (id) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        // console.log(userId);
        return Axios.post('/api/posts/like', {
            postId: id
        }).then( (like) => {
            dispatch({type: ADD_LIKE, id})
                // console.log('you have liked this', like)
        }).catch( (err)=> {
                console.log('there seem to be an error', err);
        })
```

**Full Reducer**

```
import { ADD_LIKE, GET_LIKES_COUNT} from '../actions/';

const initialState = {
    post: [],
    postError: null,
    posts:[],
    isEditing:false,
    isEditingId:null,
    likes:0,
    postId:null
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_LIKES_COUNT:
            // console.log(action.data)
            return({
                ...state,
                likes:action.data
            })
         case ADD_LIKE:
            // console.log(action.id)
            return({
              ...state,
            likes: state.likes + 1
          })
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**Like Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCoffee, faAdjust } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {  getLikeCount, postLike} from '../actions/';
class Like extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            likes: null,
            heart: false
        }
    }
    // dont remove () after (id) or else infinite onClick
    clickLike = (id) => () =>  {
        this.props.postLike(id);
        // toggles between css class
        this.setState({
            heart: !this.state.heart
        })
    }
    render(){
       return(
            <div style={{float:'right', fontSize: '1.5em', color:'tomato'}} >
            <i style={{ marginRight: '140px'}} className={this.state.heart ? 'fa fa-heart':'fa fa-heart-o' }>
                    <span style={{ marginLeft: '6px'}}>
                        <a href="#" onClick={this.clickLike(this.props.like)}>Like </a>       
                    </span>
                    {/* gets the like counts */}
                    {this.props.likeCount}
                </i>
            </div>       
       )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
    likeCount:state.post.likes
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    getLikeCount: (id) => dispatch(getLikeCount(id)),
    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id))
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Like);
```

`<Like like={id}/>` post id is `id` and being passed in as a prop

**Postitem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import Editable from './Editable';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {UpdatePost, getLikeCount, postLike} from '../actions/';
import Like from './Like';
import Axios from '../Axios';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    },
    button:{
        marginRight:'30px'
    }
}
class PostItem extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            disabled: false,
        }
    }
    onUpdate = (id, title) => () => {
        // we need the id so expres knows what post to update, and the title being that only editing the title. 
        if(this.props.myTitle !== null){
            const creds = {
                id, title
            }
            this.props.UpdatePost(creds); 
        }
    }
    render(){
        const {title, id, userId, removePost, createdAt, post_content, username, editForm, isEditing, editChange, myTitle, postUpdate, likes,  clickLike} = this.props
        return(
            <div>
                   <Typography variant="h6" component="h3">
                   {/* if else teneray operator */}
                   {isEditing ? (
                          <Editable editField={myTitle ? myTitle : title} editChange={editChange}/>
                   ): (
                       <div>
                           {title}
                       </div>    
                   )}         
                   </Typography>
                   <Typography component="p">
                       {post_content}
                       <h5>
                           by: {username}</h5>
                       <Typography color="textSecondary">{moment(createdAt).calendar()}</Typography>
                       <Like like={id}/>
                   </Typography>
                   {!isEditing ? (
                       <Button variant="outlined" type="submit" onClick={editForm(id)}>
                           Edit
                       </Button>
                   ):(     
                       // pass id, and myTitle which as we remember myTitle is the new value when updating the title
                        <div>
                            <Button 
                                disabled={myTitle.length <= 3}
                                variant="outlined" 
                                onClick={this.onUpdate(id, myTitle)}>
                                Update
                            </Button>
                            <Button 
                                variant="outlined" 
                                style={{marginLeft: '0.7%'}}
                                onClick={editForm(null)}>
                                Close
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                   )}
                   {!isEditing && (
                    <Button
                        style={{marginLeft: '0.7%'}}
                        variant="outlined"
                        color="primary"
                        type="submit"
                        onClick={removePost(id)}>
                        Remove
                    </Button>
                    )}
           </div>
       )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // pass creds which can be called anything, but i just call it credentials but it should be called something more 
    // specific.
    UpdatePost: (creds) => dispatch(UpdatePost(creds)),
    getLikeCount: (id) => dispatch(getLikeCount(id)),
    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id))
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
});
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PostItem);
```

**PostList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {DeletePost,  getLikeCount, postLike, UpdatePost,EditChange, DisableButton} from '../actions/';
import PostItem from './PostItem';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    }
}
class PostList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            title: '',
        }
    }
    // Return a new function. Otherwise the DeletePost action will be dispatch each
     // time the Component rerenders.
    removePost = (id) => () => {
        this.props.DeletePost(id);
    }
    onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            title: e.target.value
        })
    }
    formEditing = (id) => ()=> {;
        this.props.EditChange(id);
    }
    getLikes = (id) =>  {
        // console.log(id);
        this.props.getLikeCount(id)
        console.log(this.props.likeCount)
    }
    render(){
        const {posts} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {posts.map((post, i) => (
                    <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                     {this.getLikes(post.id)}
                    {/* {...post} prevents us from writing all of the properties out */}
                        <PostItem
                             myTitle={this.state.title} 
                             editChange={this.onChange} 
                             editForm={this.formEditing} 
                             isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id} 
                             removePost={this.removePost} 
                             {...post} 
                        />
                    </Paper>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // pass creds which can be called anything, but i just call it credentials but it should be called something more 
    // specific.
    EditChange: (id) => dispatch(EditChange(id)),
    UpdatePost: (creds) => dispatch(UpdatePost(creds)),
    getLikeCount: (id) => dispatch(getLikeCount(id)),
    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id)),
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
    DeletePost: (id) => dispatch(DeletePost(id))
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList);
```

Edit

**Actions.js**

```
export const getLikeCount = (id) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return Axios.get(`/api/posts/likes/count/${id}`)
            .then( (res) => {
                 const data = res.data
                 console.log(data); // logs data and i can see an array 
                 dispatch({type: GET_LIKES_COUNT, data})
             })

    }
}
```

{this.props.likeCount} logs

[image]

[image]

ive tried doing this

```
case ADD_LIKE:
    return {
    ...state,
    posts: state.posts.map(post => {
      if (post.id === action.id) {
        return {
          ...post,
          likes: post.likes + 1
        }
      } else return post
    })
  };
```

but it does not update the like count for some reason.

Comment: You have only one counter for likes in state? If you want to have different numbers, then you need different states for that

Comment: did you mean post.id is postId in your state. because you can not compare
if(action.id === post.id) then do  likes: state.likes + 1 like this because post is array.

Comment: Maintaining likes in the state doesn't makes sense unless you are maintaining the number of posts liked by user which this redux state tracks. You'd need to update the `posts` array to increment the number of likes for that particular post.

Comment: @DeepakKhillare please check comments below sathish solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your code works, but I assume `Like` component is like a love icon for each post? But from your code, seems like all the `Like` components are sharing the same redux state `post.likes`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
    likeCount:state.post.likes
})
```

That is why all the `Like` share the same likes count. I will suggest to restructure your redux state, such as putting the likes count into the post object, for example:

**Reducer**

```
import { ADD_LIKE, GET_LIKES_COUNT} from '../actions/';

const initialState = {
    post: [],
    postError: null,
    posts:[], // put likes count in post item, for eg { id: number, likes: number }
    isEditing:false,
    isEditingId:null,
    postId:null
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
         case ADD_LIKE:
            return({
              ...state,
            posts: state.posts.map(post => (post.id === action.id ? { ...post, likes: post.likes + 1 } : post))
          })
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Then instead of use Redux in `Like` component, just passed the data from `PostItem` will be more easy to maintain:

**PostItem**

```
render() {
    return (
        ....
        <Like likeCount={post.likes} onClick={() => this.onClick(post.id)} />
        ....
    )
}
```

Comment: im still trying to work this logic, but will accept as answer.

Comment: yea sure, let me know again if you face any problem :)

Comment: it didn't work really work. ill post the likeCount log, because i can actually get a list of values, but it needs to know where to put it for each post

Comment: Im just back at square one, with the original code. I apologize, because i actually missed a portion of the code that actually handled get the post like counts.

Comment: In an simple way, how would i be able to tell redux to filter through the array `action.data`, and set the postLikeCount for that specific post.id

Comment: becuase its getting the values for sure, but is setting the wrong value for the wrong post. Essentially setting them all to the value of 7.

Comment: hi @MrPatel sorry for late reply, kind of busy these days, i trying to create a sample code for you based on your codes to refer https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-84jjty, i think you have to double check on the ID and maybe printing your redux state out to make sure it's work as expected

Comment: let me give this a shot sorry for late reply.

Comment: thank you putting time into the code, i will use this logic in my app. thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

try this,
did you mean post.id instead of postId in your state. because you can not compare if(action.id === post.id) then do likes: state.likes + 1 like this because post is array.

if you wrongly used post.id instead of postId you can try below solution

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_LIKES_COUNT:
            // console.log(action.data)
            return({
                ...state,
                likes:action.data
            })
         case ADD_LIKE:
            // console.log(action.id)
            return({
              ...state,
            likes: action.id === state.postId? state.likes + 1 : state.likes
          })
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. i will post how im getting post.id. one sec.

Comment: `action.id` gets the post.id but i need a way to make state.likes upvote only the post containing the `action.id`.

Comment: if i do   `likes: action.id !== state.postId? state.likes + 1 : state.likes` it will update state for all post still

Comment: That means the data type in `action.id` and `state.postId` is not same. You may want to use `parseInt` function to cast the value to integer.